# How to create GA event for New Registration in "user_register" Wordpress hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

So basically On My WordPress site I have 3 different ways to register (std Reg. Form, Social Media Plugin, Membership Reg.) this way I am tracking new user registration through **"user_register"** Wordpress hook and sending notification by email to CEO,

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'new_registration_email_notification', 10, 1 );

function new_registration_email_notification( $user_id )
{
    global $current_user;

    wp_mail( $multiple_recipients, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

In addition I need to add Google Analytics event in "user_register" hook in order to "catch" all 3 registration ways, I have already understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560994/why-google-analytics-doesnt-track-all-my-events-with-setcustomvar)  that it supposed to be GA client written in PHP but I don't really see that it will do the work like std GA javascript.

```
var Register= document.getElementById("Register");          
Register.onclick = function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Register', 'Click/Touch');
```

Didn't find much info about it, so if somebody could help with some explanation it would be great.

Comment: If yours social plugin runs the native social platform api, maybe you can use its events. Check:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button#settings

I think it's better to maintain the event trigger at the client side.

Comment: i am using ONEALL wordpress plugin for Social Netwrok connection ,, found some hook's that happens after new user registered                    function oa_social_login_do_after_user_insert ($user_data, $identity)           tried  to add some basic javasript  to see if it's working but it's not probably because it's running on the server side too....    i am kinda despaired because can't find any solution about this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

This may be of use to you: [Track event in google analytics upon clicking form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit)

I know there is tracking for on-click submissions, I didn't see much on the resource link you provided.

edit: By creating a callback on the submit button, you can track your registers that way.

Comment: this is  not enough because I don't have access to the social login button that provided with plugin ,, I need somehow to trigger it through the "user_register" hook ...